# Halide: Using constant_exterior() + vectorize() in OpenCL

Tags: opencl, scheduling, halide

I can't generate an OpenCL implementation with Halide when I choose a constant_exterior() type of boundary condition with vectorize scheduling.

When compiling, I get the following error:

```
Error:
Vector of bool not valid in OpenCL C (yet)
```

I don't understand why it would need to use a boolean vector..

My function looks something like this:

```
void dummy_step()
{
    Var x("x"), y("y"), c("c");
    Func src("src");
    Func dst("dst");

    // input parameters
    ImageParam image(UInt(8), 3, "inputImage");
    Param<int> W;
    Param<int> H;

    // boundary condition
    src = constant_exterior(image, 0, 0, W, 0, H);

    Expr x0 = cast<int>(x + y);
    Expr y0 = cast<int>(x - y);

    dst(x, y, c) = cast<uint8_t>(clamp(src(x0, y0, c), 0.0f, 255.0f));

    // scheduling
    dst.vectorize(x, 4).gpu_tile(x, y, 16, 8).compute_root();

    dst.compile_to_file("test", {image, W, H});
}
```

If I remove `.vectorize(x, 4)`, the code compiles. If I use another boundary condition, let's say, `src = repeat_edge(image, 0, W, 0, H);` it also works.

Answer (score 1):

constant_exterior checks if each x coordinate in the vector is within the bounds in order to mux between the constant exterior value and the interior values. The result of this check is a vector of booleans. repeat_edge doesn't need to do that check - it can just clamp the coordinates directly using min and max operations.

I suggest not vectorizing this part of the code using a schedule like so:

```
    src.compute_at(dst, x);
    dst.vectorize(x, 4).gpu_tile(x, y, 16, 8).compute_root();
```

Comment: Strikes me as a bug in Halide though. Should be possible to fix codegen for this, but at the very least there should be a better error message.

Comment: I tried using the scheduling you proposed but it tells me that "constant_exterior" is computed at an invalid location.